# Definition of mean and median

Tags: statistics

What is the motivation and intuition behind these definitions?

> $Mean = argmin_aE(x-a)^2$
>   $Median = argmin_aE|x-a|$

My lecture note uses partial differentiation with respect to a to prove these.Why not with respect to x?Btw, could someone give some books or other sources that include these definitions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The motivation is straight forward, you want to find a single constant ($a$) that best represents the random variable $\omega \mapsto x(\omega)$.

There are many notions of 'best', the question provides two ways of quantifying the 'error', one is
$E (x-a)^2$, the other is $E|x-a|$.

The random variable $x$ is fixed, you want to choose the (or an) $a$ that corresponds to the $\min$ error. That is why you are interested in the change with respect to $a$.

(**Very** loosely speaking, the $L_2$ cost is good at dealing with noisy data and the $L_1$ cost is good a dealing with outliers.)

Comment: The equation of mean look similar to variance.Why (x-a) has to raised to a specific power(i.e. 2)?

Comment: @xyzabc: I suspect the 2 arose because it was computationally tractable.

Answer (score 1):

Because $x$ here is the random variable having with $\arg\min_a E(x-a)^2$ as its mean

The motivation came from this, if $a$ is any real number, we can interpret E(x-a)^2 as an squared error of $a$ towards $x$, then
\begin{eqnarray*}
E(x-a)^2=(a-E(x))^2+\sigma^2_x
\end{eqnarray*}

so if we want to minimise the error, we need to take $a=E(x)$ which is mean

same goes for median, but the error is $E|x-a|$ instead

Comment: Could you justify the equation $E(x-a)^2=(a-E(x))^2+\sigma^2_x$?

Answer (score 0):

Similar relationships hold for sample means and variances. In that case,
it is easy to illustrate them graphically.

I use a sample of size $n = 100$ from an exponential distribution with
rate $\lambda = 1/50,$ which implies a population mean $\mu = 50$ and
population median $\eta = 34.657.$ I deliberately chose an exponential
sample so that the mean and median would be different.
For my particular sample the sample mean is $\bar X = 52.20$ and
the sample median is $\tilde X = 38.92.$

Let $Q(c) = \frac 1n \sum_{i=1}^{n}(X_i - c)^2$ and 
$A(c) = \frac 1n\sum_{i=1}^{n}|X_i - c|.$

Then we can plot $Q(c)$ against $c$ to show that $Q$ is minimized at 
the sample mean $c = \bar X$ and plot $A(c)$ against $c$ to show that $A$
is minimized at the sample median $c = \tilde X.$

[image]

*Note:* These relationships are the motivation for defining 
two measures of sample variability: the sample variance
in terms of $\sum_i (X_i - \bar X)^2$ and the sample mean absolute deviation (sometimes abbreviated as MAD)
in terms of $\sum_i |X_i - \tilde X|.$